# Testing with Spring JPA + Mock Database + @Transactional + JUnit

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, jpa, junit

So I have a method in my controller that performs an inster. Currently this method is working fine in the controller, but I am having difficulty getting the same functionality in my JUnit, and with my test database. I know there's some configuration that I'm missing somewhere.

Here's how I have my test class set up.

```
    import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup;
    import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
    import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
    import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
    import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
    import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
    import static org.junit.Assert.*;

    import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
    import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

    import org.junit.Before;
    import org.junit.BeforeClass;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
    import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
    import org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListeners;
    import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests;
    import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
    import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
    import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

    import com.bdc.am.repositories.ClientRepository;
    import com.bdc.am.repositories.ContractRepository;

    import org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener;



    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest
    @TestExecutionListeners({TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class})
 // I've heard that this Listener allows me to use Transactions in my test class, but so far it hasn't worked for me. 
    public class DbcAmServiceTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

        private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DbcAmServiceTest .class);

        private MockMvc mockMvc;

        @Autowired
        private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

        @Autowired
        ClientRepository ClientRepo;

        @Autowired
        ContractRepository ContractRepo;

        @PersistenceContext 
        EntityManager em;

        @BeforeClass
        public static void beforeClass() throws Exception{
            //set the system property to test so that the test database is used
            System.setProperty("ENVNAME","JUNIT");

        }
        @Before
        public void setup() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
}
```

Skipping tests which are fine, then the actual method within my test class which is giving me trouble:

```
    @Test
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void testUpdateandInsert(){

        LOGGER.info("==============Starting updateAndInstertTest================");

        try{

            int beforeUpdate = super.countRowsInTable("test_database");
//^This handy method allows me to count the rows in the database before performing the update



            String json = "{\"contractNum\":\"123456\",\"clientNum\":\"123456\",\"action\":\"update",\"State\":\"NY\"," +
                    "\"City\":\"New York",\"changeDate\":\"08/30/2016 11:35:59\"}";

            this.mockMvc.perform(post("/am/updateAmContract").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(json))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.status").value("Success"))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.statusMessage").value("Success"));

            int afterUpdate = super.countRowsInTable("test_database");
            assertEquals(beforeUpdate + 1, afterUpdate);
//ideally I should be able to query again and see that one extra row has been inserted, but at the moment both these checks return 7.
```

So essentially, while I can get `@Transaction` annotation to work in my main controller method, there seems to be something entirely different I'd need to do to update my in-memory test database. Any ideas on how to permit this to happen? Thanks everyone.

Comment: Your test method is transactional... There is only data in the database after a commit which will commence AFTER the method has finished. Next to that you are using JPA so if there is nothing being flushed the state hasn't been synchronized. Inject the `EntityManager` into your test, simulate a commit by doing `em.flush()` before counting the rows in the table after the insert. [Here](https://spring.io/blog/2008/01/04/before-a-jdbc-operation-flush-the-hibernate-session-includes-tse-example-code) is an old blog doing that for a plain `SessionFactory`, but should be easy to adapt.

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thanks so much. I did assume that I did not need the em.flush() because that was happening in the controller that was being called, but you do need it in the test method. Also I would add that the  @TestExecutionListeners({TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class}) was a problem. So I took it out. It was throwing an error saying that a Transaction could not occur while another transaction was taking place. With those two changes it worked, Thanks for your help!